# Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a problem in the register page, the program is running normally but unable to communicate with firebase whatever i do. I have my API key, Project ID and App ID all double checked on both firebase and my json file and they are the same but still not working

SignupActivity.java

```
    package activity.classes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.Objects;

import Entity.User;

public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private EditText signupActivityPassword ;
    private EditText signupActivityEmail ;
    private EditText signupActivityFullName ;
    private EditText signupActivityConfirmPassword ;
    private Button registerBtn;

    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup_activity);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        signupActivityPassword = findViewById(R.id.signupActivityPassword);
        signupActivityEmail = findViewById(R.id.signupActivityEmail);
        signupActivityConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.signupActivityConfirmPassword);
        signupActivityFullName = findViewById(R.id.signupActivityFullName);
        registerBtn = findViewById(R.id.signupActivityRegisterBtn);

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                confirmInput(v);
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean validateEmail()
    {
        String emailInput = signupActivityEmail.getText().toString().trim();

        if(emailInput.isEmpty())
        {
            signupActivityEmail.setError("Field can't be empty");
            signupActivityEmail.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            signupActivityEmail.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateFullName()
    {
        String fullNameInput = signupActivityFullName.getText().toString().trim();

        if(fullNameInput.isEmpty())
        {
            signupActivityFullName.setError("Field can't be empty");
            signupActivityFullName.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        else if (fullNameInput.length() > 15)
        {
            signupActivityFullName.setError("Full name too long");
            signupActivityFullName.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            signupActivityFullName.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validatePassword()
    {
        String passwordInput = signupActivityPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(passwordInput.isEmpty())
        {
            signupActivityPassword.setError("Field can't be empty");
            signupActivityPassword.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            signupActivityPassword.setError(null);
            return true;
        }

    }

    private boolean validateConfirmPassword()
    {
        String confirmPasswordInput = signupActivityConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(confirmPasswordInput.isEmpty())
        {
            signupActivityConfirmPassword.setError("Field can't be empty");
            signupActivityConfirmPassword.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(!confirmPasswordInput.equals(signupActivityPassword.getText().toString().trim()))
        {
            signupActivityConfirmPassword.setError("Passwords don't match");
            signupActivityConfirmPassword.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            signupActivityConfirmPassword.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void registerUser()
    {
        String email = signupActivityEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = signupActivityPassword.getText().toString();
        String fullName = signupActivityFullName.getText().toString().trim();

        mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
        {

            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
            {

                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    User user = new User(fullName, email);

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users: ").child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                    .getCurrentUser()).getUid()).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                        {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Registration Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(mFirebaseAuth != null)
        {
            //handle the already logged in user
        }

    }

    public void confirmInput(View v)
    {
        if(!validateFullName() | !validateEmail() | !validatePassword() | !validateConfirmPassword())
        { return; }
        else
        {
            registerUser();
        }
    }

}
```

Whenever i put my credentials and click on register it says the "Registration Unsuccessful" line

Logcat:

```
    2020-09-24 21:04:46.299 23253-23253/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-09-24 21:04:46.300 23253-23253/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-09-24 21:04:46.306 23253-23253/? I/ctivity.classe: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-09-24 21:04:48.094 23253-23253/activity.classes I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2020-09-24 21:04:48.172 23253-23283/activity.classes I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:17 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0
2020-09-24 21:04:48.172 23253-23283/activity.classes I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
2020-09-24 21:04:48.180 23253-23287/activity.classes D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-09-24 21:04:48.196 23253-23287/activity.classes I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-09-24 21:04:48.196 23253-23287/activity.classes I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-09-24 21:04:48.196 23253-23283/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Unsupported class loader
2020-09-24 21:04:48.200 23253-23283/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2020-09-24 21:04:48.206 23253-23287/activity.classes D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocket(56) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2020-09-24 21:04:48.225 23253-23293/activity.classes W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2020-09-24 21:04:48.240 23253-23253/activity.classes I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-09-24 21:04:48.277 23253-23296/activity.classes W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2020-09-24 21:04:48.291 23253-23296/activity.classes I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
2020-09-24 21:04:48.420 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.420 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.420 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.420 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.420 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.432 23253-23283/activity.classes V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-09-24 21:04:48.439 23253-23297/activity.classes V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
2020-09-24 21:04:48.450 23253-23297/activity.classes V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: activity.classes, 1:943162878583:android:30e30d3ecfafefae573472
2020-09-24 21:04:48.452 23253-23297/activity.classes I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 31049
2020-09-24 21:04:48.452 23253-23297/activity.classes I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-09-24 21:04:48.453 23253-23297/activity.classes I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app activity.classes
2020-09-24 21:04:48.453 23253-23297/activity.classes D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-09-24 21:04:48.457 23253-23253/activity.classes I/MultiWindowDecorSupport: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@353846a[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
2020-09-24 21:04:48.458 23253-23253/activity.classes D/MultiWindowDecorSupport: setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@353846a[]
2020-09-24 21:04:48.512 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.540 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.544 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.566 23253-23297/activity.classes V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-09-24 21:04:48.579 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.579 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.579 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.580 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.580 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.580 23253-23253/activity.classes W/ctivity.classe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (light greylist, reflection)
2020-09-24 21:04:48.622 23253-23297/activity.classes V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-09-24 21:04:48.662 23253-23297/activity.classes V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-09-24 21:04:48.752 23253-23287/activity.classes W/Firebase-Installations: Error when communicating with the Firebase Installations server API. HTTP response: [400 Bad Request: {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "API key expired. Please renew the API key.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
          {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
            "links": [
              {
                "description": "Google developer console API key",
                "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/943162878583/apiui/credential"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ]
2020-09-24 21:04:48.753 23253-23287/activity.classes W/Firebase-Installations: Firebase options used while communicating with Firebase server APIs: AIzaSyDMvMTiaJ8DmpnEgJxvPsrrQO7pAsKIPRM, incubation-83a90, 1:943162878583:android:30e30d3ecfafefae573472
2020-09-24 21:04:48.753 23253-23287/activity.classes E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
2020-09-24 21:04:48.765 23253-23279/activity.classes E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.setDefaultAttributesToBundle(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:55)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.startRpc(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:37)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.getToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:13)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.lambda$getInstanceId$2$FirebaseInstanceId(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:164)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId$$Lambda$4.start(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.RequestDeduplicator.getOrStartGetTokenRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:14)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.lambda$getInstanceId$3$FirebaseInstanceId(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:163)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId$$Lambda$1.then(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:382)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$2(FirebaseInstallations.java:350)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2020-09-24 21:04:48.779 23253-23287/activity.classes I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-09-24 21:04:48.779 23253-23287/activity.classes I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-09-24 21:04:48.825 23253-23297/activity.classes V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 95124216
2020-09-24 21:04:48.827 23253-23253/activity.classes D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2020-09-24 21:04:48.834 23253-23253/activity.classes D/EmergencyMode: [EmergencyManager] android createPackageContext successful
2020-09-24 21:04:48.859 23253-23253/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=70
2020-09-24 21:04:48.860 23253-23253/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@d6de8f5[SignupActivity]: setView = DecorView@353846a[SignupActivity] TM=true MM=false
2020-09-24 21:04:48.876 23253-23297/activity.classes I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2020-09-24 21:04:48.891 23253-23287/activity.classes W/Firebase-Installations: Error when communicating with the Firebase Installations server API. HTTP response: [400 Bad Request: {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "API key expired. Please renew the API key.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
          {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
            "links": [
              {
                "description": "Google developer console API key",
                "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/943162878583/apiui/credential"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ]
2020-09-24 21:04:48.892 23253-23287/activity.classes W/Firebase-Installations: Firebase options used while communicating with Firebase server APIs: AIzaSyDMvMTiaJ8DmpnEgJxvPsrrQO7pAsKIPRM, incubation-83a90, 1:943162878583:android:30e30d3ecfafefae573472
2020-09-24 21:04:48.893 23253-23287/activity.classes E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
2020-09-24 21:04:48.913 23253-23287/activity.classes I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-09-24 21:04:48.913 23253-23287/activity.classes I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-09-24 21:04:48.980 23253-23297/activity.classes V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-09-24 21:04:48.986 23253-23297/activity.classes V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-09-24 21:04:48.990 23253-23253/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@d6de8f5[SignupActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x7 surface={true 3894890496} changed=true
2020-09-24 21:04:48.998 23253-23303/activity.classes I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-09-24 21:04:48.998 23253-23303/activity.classes I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-09-24 21:04:48.998 23253-23303/activity.classes I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-09-24 21:04:48.999 23253-23303/activity.classes D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-09-24 21:04:49.018 23253-23287/activity.classes W/Firebase-Installations: Error when communicating with the Firebase Installations server API. HTTP response: [400 Bad Request: {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "API key expired. Please renew the API key.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
          {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
            "links": [
              {
                "description": "Google developer console API key",
                "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/943162878583/apiui/credential"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ]
2020-09-24 21:04:49.018 23253-23303/activity.classes D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
2020-09-24 21:04:49.018 23253-23303/activity.classes D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xe9d05240, 0xe8275008
2020-09-24 21:04:49.019 23253-23287/activity.classes W/Firebase-Installations: Firebase options used while communicating with Firebase server APIs: AIzaSyDMvMTiaJ8DmpnEgJxvPsrrQO7pAsKIPRM, incubation-83a90, 1:943162878583:android:30e30d3ecfafefae573472
2020-09-24 21:04:49.019 23253-23287/activity.classes E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
2020-09-24 21:04:49.040 23253-23287/activity.classes I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-09-24 21:04:49.040 23253-23287/activity.classes I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-09-24 21:04:49.063 23253-23303/activity.classes D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-09-24 21:04:49.103 23253-23253/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@d6de8f5[SignupActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=[0,0][720,1280] ci=[0,48][0,0] vi=[0,48][0,0] or=1
2020-09-24 21:04:49.103 23253-23253/activity.classes D/ViewRootImpl@d6de8f5[SignupActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2020-09-24 21:04:49.104 23253-23253/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@353846a[SignupActivity]
2020-09-24 21:04:49.104 23253-23253/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-24 21:04:49.106 23253-23282/activity.classes E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: FIS_AUTH_ERROR. Won't retry the operation.
2020-09-24 21:04:49.123 23253-23253/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@353846a[SignupActivity]
2020-09-24 21:04:49.123 23253-23253/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-24 21:04:49.123 23253-23253/activity.classes V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=activity.classes ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2020-09-24 21:04:49.123 23253-23253/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-09-24 21:04:49.123 23253-23253/activity.classes I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2020-09-24 21:04:49.137 23253-23297/activity.classes D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-09-24 21:04:49.137 23253-23265/activity.classes D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=80
2020-09-24 21:04:49.140 23253-23297/activity.classes V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 5
2020-09-24 21:04:49.150 23253-23253/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@353846a[SignupActivity]
2020-09-24 21:04:49.150 23253-23253/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-09-24 21:04:49.150 23253-23253/activity.classes V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=activity.classes ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2020-09-24 21:04:49.150 23253-23253/activity.classes D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-09-24 21:04:49.154 23253-23287/activity.classes W/Firebase-Installations: Error when communicating with the Firebase Installations server API. HTTP response: [400 Bad Request: {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "API key expired. Please renew the API key.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
          {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
            "links": [
              {
                "description": "Google developer console API key",
                "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/943162878583/apiui/credential"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ]
2020-09-24 21:04:49.156 23253-23287/activity.classes W/Firebase-Installations: Firebase options used while communicating with Firebase server APIs: AIzaSyDMvMTiaJ8DmpnEgJxvPsrrQO7pAsKIPRM, incubation-83a90, 1:943162878583:android:30e30d3ecfafefae573472
2020-09-24 21:04:49.156 23253-23287/activity.classes E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
```

Comment: Kindly attach onFailureListener to the user registration task, print the error in logcat and post in your question.

Comment: @s_o_m_m_y_e_e i edited the post with all of the logcat after adding onFailureListener

Comment: Did you see the message `API key expired. Please renew the API key.`?

Comment: it says to renew my API key although i just renewed it today i'm so confused

Comment: After renewing, did you update your _google services.json_ file? Moreover, have you enabled email-password authentication provider in the authentication section?

Comment: yes i did both, i will try renewing it again

Comment: It didn't work after renewing it again, i even created a new firebase project with a new key and it also didn't work... don't know what should be done here

Comment: after creating a new project in firebase i clean project and rebuild then run and it worked but now i have a new error: 'D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=81'